# Commit number for crashlytics

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have crashlytics (fabric) setup for beta testers. I've noticed a lot of the crashes are older versions of the app so the line of code is different since code has been added and deleted. Is there a way to know which commit lines up with the crashlytics version? Or is there a way to see the actual line of code on crashlytics?

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to know which commit lines up with the crashlytics version?

Yes - this is your responsibility though. You should know which commit you were on when you submitted each version of your app to the App Store. The typical way to track this is to use [git tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging). (Tag a commit when you submit it.)

That said, typically you only want to pay attention to crashes which are occurring in the newest version of your app. If they aren't reproducing in the newest version, you probably fixed them already.